# What's new in Puppet since 2007?

Tags: puppet, documentation

I've got a copy of the [*Pulling Strings with Puppet*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1590599780) book (written in 2007) but given that it has a bunch of equivocal language, I'm wonder how much has changed since then? I've found this [Release Notes page](http://projects.puppetlabs.com/projects/1/wiki/Release_Notes) and a (short) summery table at the top of the [language tutorial](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/language_tutorial.html) but neither have dates, so I don't know where to start (and the more detailed notes make for rather dry reading).

Does anyone know of a page that list thing that have changed since that book was published?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The main user-visible differences since 0.23.x are:

- more language features like better conditionals - the [Language Tutorial](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/language_tutorial.html) that you found is definitely the best way to find out what's available in manifests now.
- all your manifests and plugins (custom facts, custom types and providers) should now be in a [module directory structure](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/modules.html) and you should be using 'include mymodule::classname' instead of 'import /path/to/manifest.pp'
- as a corollary, [`puppet://` URLS for file sources](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/file_serving.html) now need to have the module path in them, like `puppet:///modules/mymodule/classname/file.txt` would live on the filesystem at `_modulepath_/mymodule/files/classname/file.txt`
- the CLI has been unified to a 'git' or 'svn' style single program with command arguments, like 'puppet agent' instead of a separate 'puppetd'. That's described [on the Tools page](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/tools.html)
- there are more built-in types and providers available, like the `yumrepo`, and `zfs` types, and `zypper`, `freebsd` , `portage` package providers.

There are big structural changes under the hood (on-the-wire communication moved from XMLRPC to a REST interface) but they're mostly invisible for every day use. The ones above are probably what trip up the most people, based on mailing list/irc inquiries.

Comment: Some elaboration on that first point wouldn't go unappreciated.

Comment: re: conditionals - you can now do 'if { a } elsif { b } else { c }' and use regexps for the conditions instead of just substring matches.

Comment: So the "more language features" is actually just "better conditionals"? OK. Just checking.

Comment: @BCS: no, there's other subtle language features, like "require => Package['foo','bar']" as a cleaner way to say "require => [Package['foo'],Package['bar']]"

Answer (score 2):

See the [Changelog](http://projects.puppetlabs.com/projects/puppet/repository/revisions/master/changes/CHANGELOG). There were quite a few updates in the past months.

Comment: Well that gives me a better idea where to start (2007 -> `ver < 0.24.x`) but I'd rather not read 3 years/+2K lines of change log. Given that book is a rather prominent stake in the sand, I'd expect a delta from there from the end user's perspective would be valuable.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have the book so I can't tell you more.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an easier to parse list compared to the changelog:
http://projects.puppetlabs.com/projects/puppet/wiki/Release_Notes

Comment: sadly it doesn't have dates so somewhere around 0.24.x I can't be sure of things are covered by the book or not.

Comment: I wouldn't use the date as a hard cut off. Also the new book is expected in March/April of this year which will cover 2.6.

You can easily find the release dates by looking at git tag on github. Here's a few to get you started:

2008-07-24 01:20:17 +0200 Updated to version 0.24.5
2008-03-25 21:27:38 +0100 Updated to version 0.24.4
2008-03-17 06:27:36 +0100 Updated to version 0.24.3
2008-03-03 17:33:08 +0100 Updated to version 0.24.2
2007-12-22 01:37:33 +0100 Updated to version 0.24.1
2007-12-13 17:41:52 +0100 Updated to version 0.24.0

Answer (score 1):

The Development Code Names should help:

http://projects.puppetlabs.com/projects/puppet/wiki/Development_Code_Names